# JavaScript Object Options

Tags: javascript

I am working on a problem set where I want to set options without having to send in all of the parameters. I have most of it working but was wondering if I can set default options that will automatically be part of the object even if not set as a property? Here is my example and you will see that I have a default option for doors, but it does not show up in the `myCar` object. I appreciate any explanation of what I am doing wrong here and how to make it work properly.

```
CarPrototype = function(options) {
  var options = options || {};

  name  = options.name;
  year  = options.year;
  doors = 4 || options.doors;
  make  = options.make;

  return options;

}

var myCar = CarPrototype({
  name: 'Ferarri',
  year:  1975,
  make: 'f50'
}};

console.log(myCar); // was hoping that doors would be part of this with default?

console.log(myCar.doors); // nothing returned :-(
```

Comment: options.doors will only get executed when 4 return false, which will never be the case.

Comment: One more error in addition to those, which are already pointed out: }}; should be });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax is invalid:

```
var options = options | {};
```

Use the or operator, `||`, instead:

```
function Car (options) {
  var options = options || {};

  this.name  = options.name;
  this.year  = options.year;
  this.doors = options.doors || 4;
  this.make  = options.make;

}
var car = new Car({name:'vanquish'});
#=> Car {name: "vanquish", year: undefined, doors: 4, make: undefined}
```

Comment: This helped me so much. I forgot that I needed `this` for the new object to reference the CarPrototype. I believe I said that right. Once I made this change, it worked great

Answer (score 2):

```
doors = 4 || options.doors
```

should be

```
doors = options.doors || 4
```

The expression gets read from left to right. The right hand of the OR will never be evaluated if the left hand returns true.